# HTTP 502.5 - ASP.NET Core cannot start in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-8

I am having trouble starting an ASP.NET Core website on IIS on a Windows Server 2012

I get the following error in the Windows EventLog:

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/IDENTITY' with physical root 'D:\CompanyName\IdentityServer\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\identityserver.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : ff.
```

I enabled stdout logging, but the log files it produces are empty = 0kb.
I updated the entire folder to have full control for the IIS Application Pool user.

I also installed the Hosting Bundle, and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable...

The application runs without problem, when I run it in the command line:

```
dotnet .\identityserver.dll
```

The only way I can get it running, it to set the Application Pool Identity to **NETWORK SERVICE**

So to me it seems it is a permission issue, but the application pool identity has accesss to everything in the websites folder??

Comment: Is the same .NET Core version you developed the application with installed on your server? And did you reboot the server after installing .NET Core?

Comment: you should add `.UseIISIntegration()` in `BuildWebHost` in `program.cs`

Comment: @ElyasEsna We use CreateDefaultBuilder, which calls UseIISIntegration by default.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have install .NET Core Runtime to you server and restart IIS? 
If already installed one. try check your Application pool > ".NET Framework version" selected at "No Managed Code"
If still don't work try change below code in "web.config"

```
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mywebsite.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
to 
  <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\mywebsite.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have done all that. And it works fine when I run it with the NETWORK SERVICE account.